# JAVA 1.5 in OSX 10.6.4

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, java-5, jgroups

I am trying to debug a j2ee application in tomcat using Intellij Idea in an OS X 10.6.4 system. I need it specifically to run over a 1.5 JVM and 1.5 JDK so that the jgroups-all component doesn't crash the application through  this error:

class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Lorg.jgroups.Address;
    at com.opensymphony.oscache.plugins.clustersupport.JavaGroupsBroadcastingListener.initialize(JavaGroupsBroadcastingListener.java:119)

Has anyone needed to install an older version of JVM or JDK in OS X before?
NOTE: I'm a Mac newbie.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java5 on Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541876/java5-on-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution [here](http://wiki.oneswarm.org/index.php/OS_X_10.6_Snow_Leopard#Workaround_for_connection_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know you should be able to choose an older VM in the Java control panel, although I think Apple removes old JREs by default now.

Did you consider Apple's [Java Deprecation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-DontLinkElementID_2) before starting you project? It looks like you will be out of luck in the near future. If Apple doesn't even want to support some recent JRE anymore it is unlikely that they will offer old, unsupported ones, which even Oracle ended support for.

Even if Oracle will provide some JRE/JDK for Mac OSX it is highly unlikely that they will back-port some Java 5 to Mac OSX. Your best bet is to migrate your application to a version which is supported first, before doing any other steps.